# Why doesn't UICollectionview frame account for header size?

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that works fine with its cells but when I added a header the bottom started getting cut off.

To be more explicit, I have a UICollectionView with 5 rows of cells, each having 160 height, and 1 header with a height of 40.

When I check the frame size of the UICollectionView it says the frame/bounds height is 800 (i.e. 160*5) but lacks the 40 pixels that are in the header view.  The result is when I use the frame size to set the content size, the header shows fine, but the bottom 40 pixels of cells get cut off.

If I change the size of the header to be huge, the header appropriately takes more space, and the same space is further clipped off the bottom :/

Shouldn't the frame's height be 840 to match its subviews or am I misunderstanding that?

Thank you,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Oops ok, I figured this one out but I'll leave my mistake with an answer for posterity:

My issue was the I had switched what I had meant to do.  My purpose was to make it so that the UICollectionView doesn't scroll, which meant the uiCollectionView.frame.size and the uiCollectionView.contentsize had to match.

My mistake was that I forgot that it is the contentSize property that scales to match the content, and you assign that size to the uicollectionview.frame.size, not the other way around.

Hope I saved someone time by documenting my mistake.